# How to remove at job generated by www-data with another Linux user

Tags: debian, user-permissions, at

Script executed by www-data creates an at job.

Afterwards, normal Linux user cannot remove this job (atrm) because "Not owner".

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Use `sudo atrm <job-number>`.

Comment: This does not solve the issue: The user I need to cancel the job is not a sudoer (and I don't want it to be sudoer).

Comment: Then only allow the user to execute `sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/atrm`? would be an option?

Comment: Certainly, it would!

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to use `sudo` to remove another user's job. To limit the`sudo` command of the user that should be able to kill the job, add a `sudo` rule as follows.

```
user ALL=(www-data) /usr/bin/atrm
```

Where

- `user` is the username you want to be able to kill the job
- `ALL` is the hostname that is allowed
- `www-data` is the user which is allowed to run this command
- `/usr/bin/atrm` is the command that the `user` is allowed to run.

Now your `user` can execute `atrm` as the user `www-data`.

```
sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/atrm <job-number>
```

Comment: Thank you. I did it like this and it worked. Regards.